# CollectionView Cell size to fit Label

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have set up a collection view using which scrolls horizontally and displays the elements in the ‘companies’ array.

[image]

The cells automatically resize relative to the label width.

I have used the code & storyboard constraints below to achieve this:

```html
class addTextStatus: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var companies: [String] = ["Everyone","Limited", "Friends", "Only Me", "Test Length Cells", ]

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad(){

              collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "statusCompanyCollectionView", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell4")

        if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1,height: 1)

        }

        userImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        userImage.layer.cornerRadius = userImage.frame.height/2
        userImage.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {

       dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.default  
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.companies.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell4 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell4", for: indexPath) as! statusCompanyCollectionView

        cell4.company.text = self.companies[indexPath.item]

        return cell4
    }

    }
```

[image]

However the issue is that when I add a UIImage view behind the label and assign constraints which dictate that it should be the same size and position as the label do I get the unexpected result below:

[image]

When in actuality I would like to achieve the following:

[image]

The constraints I have used to apply the image behind are below:

[image]

Interestingly when I use a UIView instead of a UIImage view it works as expected, I do however need to use image views in this instance.

Why is this occurring and how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: For me it looks like _one of the issue_ might be in content **hugging** and content **compression resistance** priorities being improperly configured for labels. As a side note, consider to use [`UIStackView`](https://www.raywenderlich.com/160646/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views-2) which I found more easily to do Auto Layout with when stacking views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Labels have intrinsic size. 
Image views have intrinsic size.

When you equate the width of the label and image view, auto-layout can't decide which one should change size to satisfy the constraint.

You need to disambiguate that by lowering the Content Hugging and Content Compression Resistance priorities of your image view.

You might end up with Label CH=251, CCR=750 and Image View CH=240, CCR=740 for example.

Then, during auto-layout, the intrinsic size of your label will win and the image view will take on the size of the label.

Plain views don't have intrinsic size so there was no ambiguity when you tried that option (the label won by default).  You would see the same ambiguity if you tried to equate the widths of two labels.

Comment: Hi, Just wanted to say thank you not only for offering a working solution, but also for the clear and concise explanation :) much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove Center Horizontally and Center Vertically Constraints.
2. Add Leading and Trailing Constraints from `UIImageView` to `UILabel`.

You Only need to add four Constraints (`Leading,Trailing,Equalwidth,EqualHeight`) from `UIImageView` to `UILabel`.